# How to add more increments to a ggplot bubble plot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a plot I have:

[image]

The legend is the size of the bubbles, but as you can see there are bubbles on the plot that are smaller than on the legend.

How do I add more increments in the legend to fix this?

Here is my code:

`ggplot(bef.data.frame, aes(x=u,y=v)) + 
  geom_point(col = "blue", aes(size = n)) +
  labs(x = "Distance", y = "Semivariance", title = "Omnidirectional Semivariogram") +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = fit), data = fitted_variofit(variofit.bef), size = 1)`

Comment: Look at `scale_size`.

Comment: Thank you! I investigated and the specific code you want to add is:               scale_size_area(breaks = c( insert your breaks here))    your breaks are the number and the delineation of your points in your legend.